# How to merge several csv's into a single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 6 csv files with identical headers. I am trying to remove index 0 and merge them into a single dataframe. One problem I keep running into is I only seem to access the last file in glob.

```
import glob
import csv
import pandas as pd

for item in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    with open(item, 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
```

any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try printing `item` before opening the file?  Or just printing `glob.glob("*.csv")`?  What happened?

Comment: The example code you posted works for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

dfs = []
for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(file))
pd.concat(dfs)
```

Or even in a single line:

```
pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in glob.glob("*.csv")])
```

`pandas` has a function to read a single `.csv` file. So I suggest using `pd.read_csv(filename)` (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for details) in your loop to make a `DataFrame` for every csv file. You can append all your `DataFrames` to a list.

After your loop you can `concat` all `DataFrames` using `pd.concat([df1, df2, ...])`, passing that list (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for details).

Comment: Brilliant. I knew I was swirling around the right answer but just missing it.